# ¿Como puedo saber el user name de SQL Server en Docker?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, docker, sequelize.js, sequelize

estoy realizando un proyecto con Node.js, express y Sequelize, utilizando SQL Server con docker.

Bueno el problema es que me esta dando el siguiente error `throw new sequelizeErrors.AccessDeniedError(error);` por lo que entendí es que mi user name o alguna variable de configuración, no esta correcta, pero tampoco se de donde sacar el user name, como tengo SQL en Docker, tal vez sea diferente, bueno en fin, probé utilizando esta consulta `SELECT USER_NAME();` la cual me retorno esto `Dbo` intente con esto y no funciona, también intente con `sa`, `SA`, `sql1` y siguió sin funcionar.

Ahora les paso a mostrar un poco como es mi configuración inicial de Sequelize

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE,
    process.env.USERNAME,
    process.env.PASSWORD,
    {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DIALECT
})
```

Y bueno por ultimo les muestro el archivo .env

```
PORT=8080

#config database
DATABASE="Disney"
USERNAME="dbo"
PASSWORD="5qu4d1-Des4_p0w3r"
HOST="localhost"
DIALECT="mssql"
```

con console.log probé las variables de .env y la esta leyendo correctamente.

Este es el comando de inicio para iniciar SQL Server en Docker.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=5qu4d1-Des4_p0w3r" `
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 `
   -d `
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Con respecto a las versiones de SQL y Docker, son las mas recientes dado que lo instale el 10/09/2022, todo fue instalado con el instructivo de Microsoft.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta e incluye un fragmento más completo del error, no lo resumas. Cuál es la imagen de MSSQL que estás usando? Si es [esta](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server), tú eres quien puede definir la clave de `sa` y crear un script de entrypoint pa crear más usuarios...

Comment: Me arriesgo a pensar que quizás puedes enviar otro parámetro en el docker, parecido a `-e "MSSQL_SA_USER=user`. Investiga los parámetros que puedes pasar a la imagen `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest`